# NFC permission required in nativescript(vue.js)

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript

I am trying to develop an android NFC tools in nativescript vue.js, but I got the security exception - NFC permission required.
I had do some research in google, but I cannot find the solution.
Did anyone know how can I fix it?

```
<script>
    import Main from "./Main";
    const NFC = require("../nativescript-nfc").Nfc;
    const deviceOrientation = require("../nativescript-screen-orientation");

    var nfc = new NFC();

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                data: ""
            };
        },
        methods: {
            onLoaded() {
                deviceOrientation.setCurrentOrientation("portrait", null);
            },
            onClickRead() {
                nfc.available().then(function(available) {
                    console.log(available ? "Yes" : "No");
                });
            },
            onClickBack() {
                this.$navigateTo(Main);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Here's the relevant part from the android docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#manifest

You need to specify the `android.permission.NFC` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Where can I find the AndroidManifest.xml?In my playground only have app.js, app.css, npm packege and some vue file. I need to creat it?

Comment: You cannot edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` in the playground I'm afraid. You will have to download your playground, and build it locally on your machine. Seems like the plugin will do this automatically when built - so no need to edit the file when building locally.

Comment: It worked in local machine. Thanks

Comment: Great - I'll leave a proper answer below!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to the relevant part of the Android docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#manifest

What that means for NativeScript is that, `nativescript-nfc` needs additional permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` that are not available in the Playground.

Building the app locally should work fine - as the plugin will automatically set the correct settings in `AndroidManifest.xml`.